# SQL Server Dateadd - Get interval from if else in select query?

Tags: sql, database

Depending on Frequency Range (nvarchar), which can be 'Weekly' or 'Monthly', I would like to use the result to set the interval of the dateadd function

```
SELECT rs.ScheduledStartDate, rs.ScheduledEndDate, rs.Frequency, rs.FreqRange, rs.LastCreated
FROM RosterSchedule rs
WHERE dateadd(case when rs.FreqRange = 'Weekly' Then day else month end), rs.Frequency, rs.LastCreated) = GETDATE()
```

Comment: `GETDATE()` returns the current time to approx 3ms precision so even if that worked it is unlikely to be what you need.

Comment: i will do some conversion i just wanted to keep the query simple to focus on my question which is, how can i determine the interval of the dateadd function from another expression

Comment: You can't. You need 2 expressions or just use `day` and multiply by 7 as the datepart can't be set dynamically but if you give your actual need there may possibly be more sargable alternatives.

Comment: Ah I thought it was `day/week` so ignore the multiply by 7 stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think reverse the order of the comparison:

```
WHERE CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) = CASE
                                WHEN rs.FreqRange = 'Weekly' THEN DATEADD(Week, rs.Frequency, rs.lastcreated)
                                WHEN rs.FreqRange = 'Monthly' THEN  DATEADD(Month, rs.Frequency, rs.lastcreated)
                                ELSE '1/1/1900' -- Adjust this as needed
                                END
```

Comment: Not sure why you accepted mine when Andriy posted basically the same thing earlier, but thanks.

Comment: I guess the expression for converting `GETDATE()` to just date make your answer more complete. Either way, I agree with your arrangement too. :)

Comment: @Andriy - I +1'd you just for balance :)

Comment: We are quits then, I guess. :)

Answer (score 5):

Should possibly be something like

```
…
WHERE
  CASE
    WHEN rs.FreqRange = 'Weekly'  THEN DATEADD(WEEK,  rs.Frequency, rs.LastCreated)
    WHEN rs.FreqRange = 'Monthly' THEN DATEADD(MONTH, rs.Frequency, rs.LastCreated)
  END = today
```